# Using union in yacc file

Tags: c, yacc, unions

I'm trying to develop a basic compiler and I'm using a union for `yylval` as follows:

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct info {
  int line;
  /* details unimportant */
};
%}

%union{
  char *str;
  struct info *ptr;            
}
```

In my lexer definition, I have

```
%{
#include "parse.tab.h"
%}
```

But when I compile the generated lexer, I get the following errors:

```
y.tab.h:  unknown type name 'YYSTYPE'.
error: request for a member str in something not a structure or a union.
```

Do I need to `#define YYSTYPE` as well?

*(I edited the original question to insert enough information from the source files to make the question answerable. Any mistakes in the transcription are my fault and I apologize -- Rici.)*

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: That union declaration is fine and you should not define YYSTYPE if you use %union. Please provide more details. Does the error occur when compiling your parser or your scanner? Also what error precedes it?

Comment: @harsh: I've edited your question so as to be able to provide a meaningful answer. In the future, please make an attempt to include relevant details; a good start is to try to reduce the amount of code needed to reproduce the problem to a [mcve].

Comment: @rici, your advise helped me out a lot. The yystr error has been fixed now, I guess it was due to the position union was placed in. I've edited the code, but am still facing the second error (edited the post accordingly). I've updated the code. I still can't get what's wrong.

Comment: @HarshS.Kulshrestha: I don't think you understand the point of SO. This is not a forum in which you present your personal problem and other people engage with you to fix it. Really, you should do your own homework. The point of SO is to be a permanent encyclopedia of *good* questions and their answers, of general use to other people. I did my best to make your question and my answer fit that format, but you are not cooperating and I feel I have little option but to vote to close your question. Please see [ask].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain enough information to answer, and the provided source code links are not permanent.

Comment: @rici, alright, I'll put it down.

Comment: @HarshS.Kulshrestha: I reverted your last edit, and removed the links to your source code. Hopefully the question and answer will help someone. Please feel free to ask a different question, but do start by reading the guidelines on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you use a `%union` declaration, you must not `#define YYSTYPE`; the bison manual makes this clear.

However, any necessary declarations -- in this case, the declaration of `struct info` -- must be included in your lexer description file (`parse.l`) as well. The two generated files are independent of each other, so the fact that `struct info` is declared in the *parser* does not make the definition automatically available to the *lexer*.

In order to avoid repeating the declarations, it is usually a good idea to put them in a separate header file:

#### file: info.h (added)

```
#ifndef INFO_H_HEADER_
#define INFO_H_HEADER_
struct info {
  int line;
  /* details unimportant */
};
// ...
#endif
```

#### file: parse.y (now #include's info.h instead of the in-line struct declaration)

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "info.h"
%}
%union{
  char *str;
  struct info *ptr;
}
```

#### file: parse.l (also #includes info.h)

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/* This must come *before* including parse.tab.h */
#include "info.h"
#include "parse.tab.h"
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of how I use YYSTYPE:

```
typedef union {                         // base type filled by lexical analyzer
    struct {
        int numtype;                    // classval (type; selects into union below)
        union {
            int    ival;                    // integer value
            long   lval;                    // long value
            double dval;                    // double
        } val;
    } numval;
    unsigned char *sval;                    // string value
} lex_baseval;

typedef struct {                            // type returned by lexical analyzer
    int lineno;    
    lex_baseval lexval;
} YYSTYPE;

#define YYSTYPE YYSTYPE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can't I use the simple union declaration, for just 2 data types? I'm confused about whether to #define YYSTYE or not? The yacc documentation says I shouldn't if I've not given a name to my union.

Comment: @paul: If that works for you, it's cool, but please don't put non-conformant code in an SO answer. Please see sect. 7.1.3 of the C standard: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use." Personally I'd use a `%union` declaration for semantic values and the location stack to hold location info, but that's personal preference.

Comment: @rici, thx for the feedback. Will do that next time. This I copied from a more generic lexer/parser I use as an example for OP.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: OK, rather than downvote, I fixed the identifiers myself, by simply removing the unnecessary underscores. The `#define YYSTYPE YYSTYPE` might look strange, and I considered using `YYSTYPE_` as the typedef name to avoid raised eyebrows, but it is perfectly workable and is or should be a standard idiom. (It works because the C preprocessor won't recursively expand. So `YYSTYPE` is unreplaced (or replaced with itself, if you prefer) and the `#define` causes the `#ifdef YYSTYPE` test in the generated parser to succeed, so it doesn't attempt to define `YYSTYPE` as `int`.

Comment: @rici I've added links to my code. A lot of it is commented as I've to use that code later. Please look into it and tell me if something's wrong. I might have to take it down soon as it is supposed to be a part of my college work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your linked code is that the `%union` is *inside* the `%{`...`%}` at the top of your .y file -- which means that yacc just copies it verbatim to the y.tab.c file and does not actually process it.

This manifests most obviously as a syntax error on `%union` when you try to compile `y.tab.c`, but also means there's no `YYSTYPE` definition in `y.tab.h`, as yacc didn't see the `%union` so didn't create one.

Comment: so where should I declare it? It has to be declared after the struct.

Comment: Chris: Sorry, that was my clumsiness. I was trying to edit in the relevant parts of @Harsh's source files, and I made a copy-and-paste error. It was correct in the original, and I fixed the question.

Comment: @rici: It's incorrect in the (formerly) linked files, and if you fix it, the error in the question goes away.

Comment: @HarshS.Kulshrestha: the `%union` needs to be *after* the `%}`.